# Load Testing, Performance Testing , Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

we have sync up mechanism in this mechnaism we implemented handshake mechanism, header and footer
header intially send the data, then images send to the server S3  and footer will match the data , if the header and footer data matches then sync up successfully and if data not matches syncup failed.
i want to test this request on Jmeter

i am expecting the solution or implementation of how to test this sync up mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide a generic piece of advice:

If your "sync up" (whatever it is) uses HTTP as the transport you should be able to record the requests from "header" and "footer" (whatever they are) via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://help.blazemeter.com/docs/guide/recorders-blazemeter-chrome-extension.html) so you would be able to simulate the requests using JMeter.

Once done you can come up with "negative" test and amend the payload of one of the requests somehow. JMeter automatically treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) above 400 as successful, if it is not enough you can add your custom pass/fail criteria via [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)